# Is Coolite worth using in a medium-big project?

Tags: asp.net, extjs, coolite

I'm planning to start a web based stock and current managament project.

I want app to be Ajax but I don't want to spend my time for client-side code.

Thus, I think to use [coolite](http://www.ext.net/) for my presentation layer.

However, before starting project I want to hear some advices about it.

Is it worth using in a big project and do you have any other advice about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be much better asked on the Coolite forums where you'll hear from actual users of the framework rather than people who will just knock it because it's not jQuery (sigh).  IMHO, it is a pretty solid framework -- however, I've never used it in a production app. You really should spend some time evaluating it yourself -- take a day and mess around with their samples and see if you can build something simple.  Ultimately only you can decide if it will work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks bmoeskau, I'm just doing what you said. However, I'll wait for a whole to hear some advice about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm yet to come across a javascript to asp net framework that isn't full of bugs. I'm in the process of an application rewrite and I'm ripping out the ajax frameworks and just using jquery.

I've found it simple to code, fast to run and easy to bug fix.

I can't comment on Coolite, but for my 10c I'd suggest just learning jQuery.

Comment: I also have some experience about Jquery. But it's my second choise.

Answer (score 0):

Way back when Coolite first came out I tried it and wasn't impressed and it ties you down somewhat so I just use Ext with .NET pure, a bit more work but will save you in the long run I think and keep you flexible to changes in both frameworks.